# MS Access 2016 Treeview error: "No object in this control element. Runtime error 438"

Tags: vba, ms-access, vb6, treeview, ms-access-2016

I have a problem to open the treeview in MS Access. I think it's since the last windows update.

I'm getting an error message when I start the program:

> "There is no object in this control element.  Runtime error 438: Object
>   does not support this property or method."

The debugger marks one line yellow in the vba code: `CreateTree TreeView0.Nodes`.

I didn't change anything since the last time. There it has still worked. 
I did the following steps, but they all didn't help:

- reinstalled MS Access
- repaired MS Access
- exchanged the C:\Windows\SysWOW64\MSCOMCTL.ocx, unregistered and registered it
- updated VB6 to the latest version
- added the database again

I hope that someone can help me!

Comment: Is MS-Access 32 or 64 bits?

Comment: This is because you have 64bit version of MS Office installed. Install 32bit version and you'll see TreeView and others again.

Answer (score 2):

This is a known new bug in mscomctl.ocx in many localisations - if not all, including English.

From one of the reportings:

> Now they are experiencing the problem also with MSI installations of
>   Office 2016 which have been updated by the Windows update of Aug 1. On
>   these systems mscomctl.oxc seems to not have been updated as it still
>   showed version 6.1.98.46.
>
> They had to disinstall the update of Aug 1
>   (KB4011051 -> no mention there of this issue) to get rid of the
>   problem.

There is at this moment no info from MS when and how it will be corrected.

Comment: Could you link to the reporting that you pulled it from? I'd like to read it, myself.

Comment: Sorry, it is a snippet from an MVP closed group posting.

Comment: did not help. There is no KB4011051 on my computer.

Answer (score 0):

This may be a better long term solution for you.
https://www.access-treeview.com/
Wish you the best

Comment: please avoid [link-only answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers/8259#8259) because in future, the link could be broken

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative TreeView control is here: http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?698563-CommonControls-(Replacement-of-the-MS-common-controls)

Answer (score 0):

This is because you have 64bit version of MS Office installed. Install 32bit version and you'll see TreeView and others again.