# Mouse scrolling disabled in latest Office 2016 update

Tags: ms-access, vba

I maintain a campaign scheduling database in MS Access, built from scratch. It's been running for two years with few problems. It has a userbase of around 50 account managers.

This week, there was a Microsoft Office update which has disabled mouse scrolling on ALL forms within the database. As the forms are almost all continuous forms containing campaign scheduling details split into days, weeks and months, being able to scroll through is important. Mouse scrolling has always worked before.

Does anyone have a fix for this?

Comment: They really [botched](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45803485/ms-access-2016-treeview-error-no-object-in-this-control-element-runtime-error) this update, didn't they? See https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/bd27a445-7335-45ab-99e8-46fa04cff960/mouse-scroll-not-working-in-access-2016-form-view?forum=accessdev